# Where does PORT is stored in the next command ~PORT=8080 npm App.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Assuming we have the next code in the **App.js**,

```
console.log(`This is the port ${process.env.PORT}`);
```

Is there a way to access to the value of PORT outside the runtime process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you could use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and read the env variables from a file. Then externally, you can read that file and get the PORT variable.

Answer (score 1):

Values stored in process.env are environment variables, provided by your shell.  In a *nix environment you can access this outside of the application like

```
echo $PORT
```

In windows you can access the environment variable like so:

```
echo %PORT%
```

It is worth noting that process.env values are not variables, and if you change the values in the runtime, it will not persist outside of the application.